# Chakra ui - color mode inside extendTheme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, chakra-ui

I want to change global shadow color based on active theme color mode (dark or light). So if theme is light I want to set shadow.xl to `8px 8px 20px #fff` otherwise `8px 8px 20px #000`. I know about function like in styles.global but it is not available on shadows or extendTheme. Any ideas how to spot which color mode is active?

```
extendTheme({
  shadows: {
    // Here
    xl: '8px 8px 20px #000',
  },
  styles: {
    global: props => ({
      body: {
        color: mode(gray500, '#fff')(props),
        bg: mode(gray100, '#161616')(props),
        fontWeight: 300,
      },
    }),
  },
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While looking through chakra's default theme source code, I found this:
https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/main/packages/theme/src/styles.ts
you need to use mode() which is imported from @chakra-ui/theme-tools

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not mentioned in the docs on `extendTheme`, it [looks like](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/3adda59f95986abfc7b4d97a855900270cde2d3c/packages/react/src/extend-theme.ts#L79) `extendTheme` can also accept a function as an argument. This function is then applied to the default theme, giving you access to all of the theme's properties. In particular, you can check `theme.config.initialColorMode`, and set your shadows accordingly. That might look something like this:

```
const theme = extendTheme(currentTheme => {
  const isLight = currentTheme.config.initialColorMode === 'light';
  return {
    shadows: {
      xl: isLight ? '8px 8px 20px #fff' : '8px 8px 20px #000',
    },
    styles: {
      global: props => ({
        body: {
          color: mode(gray500, '#fff')(props),
          bg: mode(gray100, '#161616')(props),
          fontWeight: 300,
        },
      }),
    },
  };
});
```

Comment: It's not working when you change theme. InitialColorMode is a static value.

Comment: Ah! I see. I suspect that this may not be possible to do with `extendTheme`, since the "theme" objects appear to be static (although I could very well be wrong). Your best bet here might involve calling the `useColorMode` hook inside of any components that need to render shadows.

Comment: Agree, I just made a custom hook with shadow color and I will use it where needed.

Comment: If you read the code carefully, you'll see that you're supposed to modify-then-return currentTheme